# Magento 2: Adding JS from module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, javascript, frontend

I have a module, and I want to add a **javascript generated** in the module at the frontend **footer**.

The javascript has to be built dynamically because it depends on server variables. I've thought of a `phtml`.

How do I add this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add these files:

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

or

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/<frontName>_<controllerName>_<actionName>.xml
```

File content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="ModuleVendor_ModuleName::js/my_js.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

JS file:

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/my_js.js
```

JS Content:

```
'use strict';
require(["jquery", "domReady!"], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('jquery loaded with success!');
    });
});
```

---

To add some **controller** or block you can add the JS content above using a PHTML:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::my_js.phtml" name="my_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: How can I call the controller or the block from my_js?

Comment: I added in the bottom of my answer, you can add any PHP code with JS when you use PHTML file.

Comment: i have to replace the original default.xml content for last?

Comment: No, you can remove the my_js.js called before, and then add the code that I added in my answer.

Comment: it works fine!! thank you very much for help

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not to use global variables if you need data from the server.
You can pass them in other way, for example using the widget factory of jQuery UI.

In your phtml do something like:

```
<div id="element"></div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    "#element": {
        "yourJsModule": {
            "data1": <?php echo $variable ?>,
            "data2": <?php echo $variable2 ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

In your javascript

```
define([
   "jquery"
], function($){
    $.widget('vendor.module', {
        _create: function() {

            //Here your variables
            console.log(this.options);

        }

    });
    return $.vendor.module;
});
```

Add your js via require.config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            yourJsModule: 'Namespace_Module/path/javascript'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as follows

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

In before.phtml file add your code.

Comment: can i  change the block class or must be \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template ?

Comment: Yes. You can change.

Comment: where i have to put that code?